# Create View with Collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, create-view

I need to create a view from another database (linked as connectionserver) but here I need a different collation.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_table1
AS
SELECT *
FROM server2.table1;
```

How can I specify the collation by using this script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing, as a best practice you should list the columns you are selecting regardless. But once you have done that you can collate each column as you wish.

Comment: Okay i know this way... But there are many fields (50+) from each table... I hoped there is a way to collate with SELECT *

Comment: You must specify the collation per column. You could select the list of (n)varchar columns from `sys.columns` for your table and build the list of columns with the appropriate collation to then use in your create view definition.

Comment: Using [`COLLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15). You'll need to explicitly list your columns when you do this, but you should be doing that already; `SELECT *` has no business in a `VIEW` (and far too many people misunderstand how it works within object definitions).

Comment: Tables don't have fields; they have columns. An explicit column list, especially in a view, is a best practice and will facilitate adding the `COLLATE` clauses. Note that column the meta-data from the underlying tables is persisted when the view is created and will not change when the table schema changes unless to execute `sp_refreshview`.\

Comment: You can get the initial column list with `SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ',' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT * FROM server2.table1;',NULL,0);`. Then add the desired `COLLATE` clauses.

Comment: `server2.table1` That is NOT how you reference a table in a linked server.